# Do I need to make some changes in core-data model, when I make my app compatible to ios 5?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an application that is developed for ios lower than ios 5..
it uses core-data..
Now, if I upgrade it to ios 5, do I need to make some changes in the current application's data model??

Thanks in Advance
Shreya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shreya,

In a word, no. iOS v3 and v4 data models work without change in iOS v5.

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for your reply..Shreya

Comment: Shreya, if you find that I answered your question, may I suggest that you check the green checkmark next to my answer? When you do so, I benefit with added points. That's how you reward people for taking the time to answer your questions. Andrew